# Aws Sns Apple Key/Cert storage

Tags: c#, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Aws Sns for iOS requires you to provide the app's cert and priv key to setup push notifications. In a microservice architecture that means I have to come up with a way to give every instance of my service access to this rather valuable information, meaning that if any instance of my service is compromised, my app's priv. key and cert are also compromised.

**What is a platform/language independent way of storing this very valuable information that would make it accessible to any/all instances of the service?**

The service is written in .NET but we have been testing .NET Core / Mono for migrating entirely to an AWS elastic architecture running linux. As it stands today I have to bundle the certificate and key with the service to be deployed, which is terrible.

Comment: As an aside, why in the world would something like this be required? Why not use an easily revocable / changeable token setup like Google did?

Comment: Are you deploying your service in EC2?  If so, it sounds like you're looking for IAM instance roles: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: Not for some time. For now its in a local datacenter and the key and cert have to be stored on each machine, which I hate.